# Error in lqs function

Tags: r

I got this error using function `rlm` from package `MASS`:

```
x <- c(14642, 14769, 14847, 15128, 15239)
y <- c(27368, 27368, 27368, 30411, 30490)

> rlm(y~x, method = "MM")
Error in if (abs(s2/scale - 1) < 1e-05) break : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> traceback()
6: lqs.default(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14642, 14769, 14847, 15128, 15239
   ), c(27368, 27368, 27368, 30411, 30490), intercept = FALSE, method = "S", 
       k0 = 1.548)
5: lqs(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14642, 14769, 14847, 15128, 15239), c(27368, 
   27368, 27368, 30411, 30490), intercept = FALSE, method = "S", 
       k0 = 1.548)
4: do.call("lqs", c(list(x, y, intercept = FALSE, method = "S", 
       k0 = 1.548), lqs.control))
3: rlm.default(x, y, weights, method = method, wt.method = wt.method, 
       ...)
2: rlm.formula(y ~ x, method = "MM")
1: rlm(y ~ x, method = "MM")
```

It does not happen for method == "M", but I'd like to know what is happening because the above run against millions of `y~x` pairs like above (few points) and the error didn't happen until now.

Also, when I use some random numbers in place of `y` there is no problem:

```
> rlm(rnorm(5)~x, method = "MM")
Call:
rlm(formula = rnorm(5) ~ x, method = "MM")
Converged in 5 iterations

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)            x 
23.801869752 -0.001621104 

Degrees of freedom: 5 total; 3 residual
Scale estimate: 0.657
```

However, changing only `x` generates a different error:

```
> rlm(y~I(1:5), method = "MM")
Error in lm.wfit(x, y, w, method = "qr") : 
  missing or negative weights not allowed
```

So, I guess that it's because of the three identical points at the beginning, but the first error I get (`in if (abs(s2/scale - 1) < 1e-05) break`) doesn't make any sense for me. Why is a variable missing if my data have certain values and not missing for random numbers?

Comment: It's not a variable that's missing, if you simply debug and step through `lqs.default` its immediately obvious that `s2` and `scale` are both zero, hence the error. That happens during a "post-processing" step after the actual model fitting. Clearly your data are a degenerate case somehow, but I'd have to do a little reading on the details of the statistics at play here to say anything more. (Which is to say, in order to solve this problem, you will likely need a more detailed understanding of the model you're trying to fit.)

Comment: This is likely a bug: If I run your example in a 64bit R session on windows I get the same error you do. But if I run it in a 32bit session I get a result without any error or warning. I used `MASS` version 7.3-33.